# DBUnit: Depends the time to import a XML file on the delta?

Tags: database, dbunit

I analyze a test automation framework and the goal is to speed it up.

In this framework DBUnit will be used to bring database in a specific state. During the analysis I recognized the following:

- The time to import a DBUnit XML file has nothing to do with the file size
- The bigger the delta between the current database status and the status the XML file will create, the longer takes the import

Can anyone confirm or veto that, please?

If this is true, would it be faster to empty the database and apply the import file then? (No updates or deletes needed, only inserts.)

If this is false, what is the real reason for the import time?
And is there any other way to speed up the import? (Performance tips from DBUnit website are already in place.)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred and typical testing approach for fastest performance is with:

1. An in-memory/embedded database for its speed, such as Apache Derby, automatically started just before launching tests
2. No existing rows in any tables; happens automatically with an embedded database and a clean build when storing any of its files in a subdirectory of the build output dir
3. dbUnit configured with DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT [0].
4. Minimal dbUnit data for each test.

These three things should provide a good, fast setup for the tests.

> The time to import a DBUnit XML file has nothing to do with the file size

The slower the database, the slower the performance with larger data file sizes.
In my experience, the data file sizes are always small, as it is only the data needed for the test with a few extra rows to ensure query accuracy, so this becomes non-relevant.

> The bigger the delta between the current database status and the status the XML file will create, the longer takes the import

The more differences, the more statements dbUnit must generate to prep data, which take time to execute.

[0] http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/components.html#DatabaseOperation

Comment: @twaldigas does this help your situation or would you like more info?

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Yes, it helps. But the question regarding import time and delta is not answered, yet.